# javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime() give illegal argument exception

Tags: java

I am trying to convert a Gregorian date to string using javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime() which throws an illegal argument exception

Here is the code:

```
public Calendar getDate()
{

    String date = (getPObj("Date")).toString();
    System.out.println(date);
                  return date == null ? null : javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime(date);
}
```

Output:

```
date :java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1422556781908,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/New_York",offset=-18000000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=235,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=America/New_York,offset=-18000000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2015,MONTH=0,WEEK_OF_YEAR=5,WEEK_OF_MONTH=5,DAY_OF_MONTH=29,DAY_OF_YEAR=29,DAY_OF_WEEK=5,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=5,AM_PM=1,HOUR=1,HOUR_OF_DAY=13,MINUTE=39,SECOND=41,MILLISECOND=908,ZONE_OFFSET=-18000000,DST_OFFSET=0]
```

getPObj("Date") returns date in Gregorian format

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The signature of the API is `public static java.util.Calendar parseDateTime(java.lang.String lexicalXSDDateTime)` and it is mentioned that it throws `IllegalArgumentException - if string parameter does not conform to lexical value space defined in XML Schema Part 2: Datatypes for xsd:dateTime.`

In your case, you need to change the String representation.

Read [Java API Doc for DatatypeConverter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#parseDateTime(java.lang.String))